# Iot Hub and Grafana or Tableau

Tags: azure, grafana, iot, azure-iot-hub, aws-iot

I am trying to connect my [Azure IoT Hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Azure#Internet_of_Things_(IoT)) to a [Grafana](https://github.com/grafana/grafana) dashboard. I have already tried to connect my device to the cloud, but I am stuck at this point.

Is there a way to connect a Azure IoT hub to the Grafana dashboard? If so, how?

Comment: [Cloud IoT dashboards using Grafana with Azure IoT](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2021/06/15/cloud-iot-dashboards-using-grafana-with-azure-iot/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly connect Azure IoT Hub to a Grafana dashboard. It only supports two Azure-specific data sources:

- Azure Data Explorer
- Azure Monitor

You can connect Azure IoT Hub to Grafana dashboard through a VM running the Grafana website. First you have to connect IoT Hub to Azure Stream analytics and Azure Stream analytics to Azure SQL database from an SQL database. It will get data and represent it on a Grafana dashboard.

Reference: [connect a Azure IoT hub to the VM running Grafana website](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2021/06/15/cloud-iot-dashboards-using-grafana-with-azure-iot/)

[Supported Grafana data sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-grafana/how-to-data-source-plugins-managed-identity#supported-grafana-data-sources)